# How to wait for event inside for loop in VANILLA JS?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, for-loop, dom-events

I try to get 5 inputs and output the sum in the end.
The problem I don't know how to wait for an event (`onclick`), especially without `settimeout` or another time function.

This is the code:

```js
var sum = 0;
var input = document.getElementById("input");

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(input.value);
    input.value = "";
    //wait until the user submit another value
  }
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<p id="answer">answer</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. When the submit button is clicked, get the total. Why do you need a loop?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Because I want to get 5 inputs with only one input element. So I need the loop to reset the input every time, get new value and add it to the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are relying on the user pressing a button each time, you shouldn't be using a loop in the first place. Just use a counter to keep track of how many times the function has been run and when you reach the desired amount, prevent the function from doing more addition.

You also need to make sure to update the total within the function, not outside of it.

NOTES:

Since you aren't submitting any data anywhere, you shouldn't be using a `form` or a `submit` button. A regular `button` is all you want.

Set up events using `.addEventListener()`, rather than event properties like `onclick`.

Don't use `.innerHTML` when there is no HTML in the string, use `.textContent` instead.

```js
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

total.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  count++;   // Increase the counter
  
  // Check to see if we've reached the count
  if(count >= 5){ 
    this.disabled = "disabled";
    input.value="";
    answer.textContent = "The final total is: " + sum;
    return; // Exit the function
  }
  
  sum+=parseInt(input.value);
  input.value="";
  answer.textContent = sum;
  alert("Enter the next number and press the button.");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
        <input type="button" id="total" value="Add to Total">

    <p id="answer"></p>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But: 1. I don't understand what makes your function to be repeated and the count increasing. I see in the code the function runs only one time. The function repeat herself because if statement ? 2. What exactly using addeventlistner giving you instead of onclick ?

Comment: @lirsim If you are going to have a button, you need to wait for the user to click it and that means no loop. Just run the function every time the button gets clicked, meaning the user must click the button to add a new number. There are other ways to accomplish the overall task with a loop, but you wouldn't use a button in those cases. `onclick` is just a property that you set and it doesn't allow for multiple functions to be registered to that one event. As such, `.addEventListener()` is the modern approach to event binding because it allows you to manage events (single or multiple).